# Load Image into ImageView using Picasso

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, picasso

I am trying to load an image which is stored in Firebase Storage into an ImageView in one of my activities.

```
                    String image = club.getImage();
                    Picasso.get().load(image).into(imgView);
```

The above code calls the club class and gets the imageUrl which is stored in Firebase realtime database.
I keep getting an error with the "Picasso.get()" part.
It's saying "cannot resolve method 'get()'".
Anyone know how to fix this? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you added the dependency at all? have you imported it in the class?

Comment: Which version of `Picasso` library you are using?

Comment: Solved - I was using an older version of the dependency. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably because you haven't included the latest version.

Put `implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'` to your module level `build.gradle` file.

Like this:

```
dependencies { 
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
}
```